# RestTemplate not failing with 403 or 302 error when requesting secured pages

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, resttemplate

I have web app working with spring-security 4.0.1 and spring mvc 4.1.6.
It has the following spring security configuration for view page "/admin" and data API "/admin/api/properties":

```
<http pattern="/admin.*" request-matcher="regex" auto-config="false">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/api/.+" access="hasRole('ADMIN')"/>
    <logout logout-url="/admin/logout" success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
    <form-login login-page="/admin/login" login-processing-url="/admin/login"
                authentication-success-handler-ref="customSuccessHandler"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="customFailureHandler"/>
    <csrf disabled="true" />
</http>
```

This works ok. But now I am trying to test security by sending requests to "/admin" and "/admin/api/properties" via rest template with different credentials.

```
private HttpStatus fetchAccessStatusForPage(String username, String password, String requestUrl) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    String token = username + ":" + password;
    String authorizationValue = "Base " + new String(Base64.encode(token.getBytes()));
    headers.add("Authorization", authorizationValue);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<Object> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    HttpStatus resultCode;
    try {
        ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestUrl, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, Object.class);
        resultCode = responseEntity.getStatusCode();
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        resultCode = e.getStatusCode();
    }
    return resultCode;
```

But it always gives me 200 OK status code, no matter what credentials I give and no matter what api I am testing.
I also tried the following (wihout any credentials) and the response code is 200 OK too for some reason.

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<Object> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);      
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(adminPageUrl, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class);
```

Am I missing something? Why doesn't rest template fail on 403 error or at least 302 with location in header?

Also tried the following approach as well and the results are the same

```
    URL u = new URL(getPageUrl(page));
    HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    String token = username + ":" + password;
    String authorizationValue = "Base " + new String(Base64.encode(token.getBytes()));
    huc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorizationValue);
    huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
    huc.connect();
    return huc.getResponseCode()
```

Comment: Have you tested with a RESTClient like this? https://github.com/wiztools/rest-client

Comment: I used this chrome extension "Advanced Rest Client " and it shows resulsts as expected - for page it has 302 with redirect url, for api - 403.  But I need to send rest requests programatically, as the parts of E2E tests

Comment: OK, then it is weird that it works without credentials using RestTemplate.

Comment: I just tried to provide api with auto-config and <http-basic /> in spring security, and all restTemplate requets worked as expected... Maybe this connected to custom security configuration? What do you think?

Comment: HttpURLConnection hides redirects by default. Maybe you get the login page when see code 200?

Comment: unfortunately no, huc.getRequestURI() give requested url without /login.. you say it hides redirects by default. Can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent `RestTemplate` from hiding redirect by creating it something like this:

```java
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod) throws IOException
        {
            super.prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        }
    });
```

**Update:** It is generally a good idea to have a seperate HTTP chain for API, something like:

```xml
<http pattern="/admin/api/.+" request-matcher="regex" create-session="stateless">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/api/.+" access="hasRole('ADMIN')"/>
    <http-basic/>
    <csrf disabled="true" />
</http>
<http pattern="/admin.*" request-matcher="regex">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ADMIN')"/>
    <logout logout-url="/admin/logout" success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
    <form-login login-page="/admin/login" login-processing-url="/admin/login"
                authentication-success-handler-ref="customSuccessHandler"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="customFailureHandler"/>
</http>
```

Comment: thanks! now I see that both api and page has 302 (FOUND status). But why it is so? we are sending username and password..

Comment: @me1111 Separate chain for API should fix that, see update.

Comment: Thanks! <http-basic> solves the problem. Furthermore, adding it to amin page pattern configuration solves it too.